# Converting time to seconds then calculations based on this new field

Tags: sql, ms-access, time, type-conversion, ms-access-2010

I have a simple table with a number of fields but the only 3 that I'm interested in are below. I want to see if the time of the advert goes past 00:00 (midnight);

ID 
start_advert_time
advert_duration

The problem is the above time fields are just text string. So a table would look like this.

```
ID    start_advert_time  advert_duration
----  -----------------  ---------------
1234  162438             0060
1235  235900             0080
```

This means;

ID 1234, time 16:24:38 and duration is 60 seconds
ID 1235, time 23:59:00 and duration is 80 seconds

As you can see the second row will go over the midnight range and this is the rows i want to pull out. I am stump how to do this but think I'm on the right lines

I wanted to convert the string to Time if possible. Then add the seconds to this which would create an "end time". How to do this I'm not sure.

SO 16:24:38 = 59078 seconds + 60 seconds duration = 59138, which in turn is 16:25:38

SO 23:59:00 = 86340 seconds + 80 seconds duration = 86420, which in turn is 00:00:20 <- over midnight and what I need

Comment: is't second row: 1235 235000 0080 than it's 23:50 not 23:59 ?

Comment: Yes sorry, think someone changed it for me

Comment: I gave answer in TSQL. Is it ok or do You need to do this in access?

Comment: Would like it in Access 2010 please. I have tried to convert it but its not working. Im still getting used to Access myself so struggling to convert it

Comment: unfortunately they both are

Comment: @neegs i converted it for Access for You in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Assuming `start_advert_time` always contains exactly 6 characters, this should do what you want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTableNameHere
WHERE DateDiff("s", CDate(0), CDate(Format(start_advert_time, "00\:00\:00"))) + Val(advert_duration) > 86399
```

---

Here is an Immediate window session to explain how that works.

```vb
' first transform start_advert_time so that CDate() will accept it ...
start_advert_time = "162438"
? Format(start_advert_time, "00\:00\:00")
16:24:38
? CDate(Format(start_advert_time, "00\:00\:00"))
4:24:38 PM 

' what is the total of seconds in a day at the last second before midnight?
? DateDiff("s", CDate(0), #23:59:59#)
 86399 

' how many seconds does start_advert_time represent?
? DateDiff("s", CDate(0), CDate(Format(start_advert_time, "00\:00\:00")))
 59078 

' and now how many seconds when you add advert_duration?
advert_duration = "0060"
? DateDiff("s", CDate(0), CDate(Format(start_advert_time, "00\:00\:00"))) + Val(advert_duration)
 59158 

' is that total seconds greater than 86399?
? DateDiff("s", CDate(0), CDate(Format(start_advert_time, "00\:00\:00"))) + Val(advert_duration) > 86399
False

' now do same for second row of sample data ...
start_advert_time = "235900"
advert_duration = "0080"
? DateDiff("s", CDate(0), CDate(Format(start_advert_time, "00\:00\:00"))) + Val(advert_duration) > 86399
True
```

Comment: Don't know if that precision is needed here, but the count of seconds per day is 86400.

Comment: @Gustav thanks I noticed that so managed to subistute in the 86400

Comment: @HansUp Thanks for the help but i get a 'data type mismatch in criteria expression'

I have checked that start time always has 6 characters which it does. Could the issue be the duration? This is always 5 figures so 60 would be 00060. Would this affect your SQL

Comment: Do any rows have Null for `start_advert_time` or `advert_duration`?

Comment: `CDate(Format(Null, "00\:00\:00"))` triggers the type mismatch error.

Comment: @HansUp Looking at the data i dont know if this is going to work (sorry i didnt spot it). It seems the start times are based on a 24 hours clock but shifted by 6 hours so start at 06:00 - 30:00. Of course anything after 23:59 is an invalid time which is what I imagine is throwing up the error. So sorry to have wasted your time. I wish i was told this at the start

Comment: Do you get what you want if you replace `CDate(Format(start_advert_time, "00\:00\:00"))` with this? --> `DateAdd("h", -6, CDate(Format(start_advert_time, "00\:00\:00")))`

Answer (score 0):

CONVERTED TO ACCESS :

```
SELECT ID, start_advert_time, advert_duration
FROM Tabela1
WHERE (((CInt([advert_duration]))>(86400-DateDiff('s',#1/1/1999#,'1999-1-1  '+Mid([start_advert_time],1,2)+':'+Mid([start_advert_time],3,2)+':'+Mid([start_advert_time],5,2)))));
```

This should work (TSQL):

```
 SELECT  [ID]
          ,[start_advert_time]
          ,[advert_duration]
      FROM Time where CAST(advert_duration as int) > (86400- DATEDIFF(ss, cast('00:00:00.0000000' as time), STUFF(Stuff([start_advert_time],3,0,':'), 6,0,':')))
```

Comment: That looks like T-SQL, not Access SQL.

Comment: @GordThompson : Maybe he is using it do get something from code behind ?

Comment: Yes i need to do this in Access 2010.

Comment: @neegs I converted it to access for You = )

Comment: @JanWalczak thanks for the help but have encountered an issue with the start time explained above. Seems the data used 'text' for a reason as has times that are not valid